# Why does transforming shapes in Photoshop lose quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes

I've noticed that in Photoshop, when using the transform tool the shape actually loses quality.

**Zoomed-in result using the transform tool**:

[image: Zoomed-in result using the transform tool]

**Zoomed-in result using the shape menu toolbar**:

[image: Shape menu toolbar]
[image: Zoomed-in result using the shape menu toolbar]

What's the reason for this behavior? And is it possible to get the transform tool to have the same result as the Shape menu toolbar?

Comment: are you transforming vector or raster elements?

Comment: You can correct me if I'm wrong but I believe a Shape is a vector.

Comment: Are you transforming both shapes at the same time?

Comment: Nope, just a single shape. Just create a shape with a Stroke and Fill, then Cmd+T, drag out, apply the transform, then zoom in and you should see a loss in quality. Unless it's just me, then I'll know at least it's not a bug in PS.

Comment: Well it seems you don't have a perfect square, are you dragging from the corner? or from edges?  If you drag from a corner with a shape that is not square, it will try to fudge the perfect aspect ratio - which will leave those ghosted lines

Comment: Yes it is not a perfect square and it is from the corner. Is there any way to disable it trying to mess with aspect ratio? I find it a little annoying that any time I want to transform a shape, I have to manually enter values in the Shape toolbar instead of being able to drag it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Photoshop CS6 and later you can turn on "Snap vector Tools and Transform to Pixel Grid". Open preferences <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and find it at the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Vnovak! Unfortunately that preference was already selected.

Comment: Strange case.. Are you transforming manually? Via dragging of controls?

Comment: Yes I am. Cmd+T then drag.

Comment: Looks like some bug. In this case it really snaps to pixel grid.

Comment: So is there any way to transform without losing quality? For now I'm just using the Shape toolbar but it's definitely more convenient to be able to freely drag.

Comment: Anti aliasing issue maybe?

Comment: @smaili, this is not a quality issue. This is anti-aliasing in action. Edge between pixels will looks blurry. In early versions there was no snapping I describe and it was need to control and fix manually.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Is there something I can do after I transform to remove the anti-aliasing? Like a "remove anti-aliasing" button?

Comment: You can select nodes or edges with direct select arrow and move them to correct position